# Numpy producing different random numbers despite seed

Tags: python, numpy

I had a problem with NumPy producing different random numbers despite seeding.

code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(1234)

vec = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=6)

print(vec)
```

As I had set the seed, I expected `vec` to contain the same random numbers in every run.

But what I got:

1. run: `vec = [-0.80715758  0.8377004  -0.98711439 -0.23424405 -1.85368722  0.97827818]`
2. run: `vec = [-0.74409802 -0.85180205  0.84585489 -0.40506222 -1.31125093 -1.23055255]`
3. run: `vec = [ 2.21521007  1.38577035  0.25437804  0.84529466 -0.83334042  1.00452671]`

I was just posting this question when I found the solution.
But to prevent others from doing the same mistake, I thought it might be a good idea to post it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was the following:
I set the seed of `random`, not of `np.random`!

When setting the seed of the NumPy random number generator, everything works as expected:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

vec = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=6)
```

`vec` will always contain the same random numbers.